# Preserve incoming interface for answers in openwrt router

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, openwrt

I have a Openwrt router with three interfaces:

1. interface br-lan: IP: 172.16.21.1 in a LAN network (172.16.21.0/24).
2. interface eth1: IP: 172.16.22.2 a WAN network (172.16.22.0/30) with Internet access.
3. interface qmimux0: IP: 80.80.80.80 a mobile connection with Internet access.

I have the default route with the WAN connection (eth1):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.22.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     2      0        0 qmimux0
80.80.80.80    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    2      0        0 qmimux0
172.16.21.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
172.16.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     1      0        0 eth1
```

I have several iptables rules for NAT:

```
# iptables -t nat -v -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 98 packets, 5677 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  149  8737 prerouting_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom prerouting rule chain */
   65  4416 zone_lan_prerouting  all  --  br-lan *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */
    0     0 zone_wan_prerouting  all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */
    0     0 zone_mobile_prerouting  all  --  wwan0  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */
   84  4321 zone_mobile_prerouting  all  --  qmimux0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 149 packets, 8737 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 561 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 561 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    8   561 postrouting_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom postrouting rule chain */
    0     0 zone_lan_postrouting  all  --  *      br-lan  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */
    0     0 zone_wan_postrouting  all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */
    0     0 zone_mobile_postrouting  all  --  *      wwan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */
    0     0 zone_mobile_postrouting  all  --  *      qmimux0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */

Chain postrouting_lan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain postrouting_mobile_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain postrouting_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain postrouting_wan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain prerouting_lan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain prerouting_mobile_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain prerouting_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain prerouting_wan_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain zone_lan_postrouting (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 postrouting_lan_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom lan postrouting rule chain */
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  *      *       172.16.21.0/24       172.16.21.1          tcp dpt:443 /* !fw3: HTTPS to ROUTER-INT (reflection) */ to:172.16.21.1
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  *      *       172.16.21.0/24       172.16.21.1          tcp dpt:443 /* !fw3: HTTPS to ROUTER-INT 4G (reflection) */ to:172.16.21.1
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_lan_prerouting (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   65  4416 prerouting_lan_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom lan prerouting rule chain */
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       172.16.21.0/24       172.16.22.2          tcp dpt:9443 /* !fw3: HTTPS to ROUTER-INT (reflection) */ to:172.16.21.1:443
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       172.16.21.0/24       80.80.80.80         tcp dpt:19443 /* !fw3: HTTPS to ROUTER-INT 4G (reflection) */ to:172.16.21.1:443

Chain zone_mobile_postrouting (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 postrouting_mobile_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom mobile postrouting rule chain */
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_mobile_prerouting (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   84  4321 prerouting_mobile_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom mobile prerouting rule chain */
   51  3060 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:19443 /* !fw3: HTTPS to ROUTER-INT 4G */ to:172.16.21.1:443

Chain zone_wan_postrouting (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 postrouting_wan_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom wan postrouting rule chain */
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3 */

Chain zone_wan_prerouting (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 prerouting_wan_rule  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* !fw3: Custom wan prerouting rule chain */
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9443 /* !fw3: HTTPS to ROUTER-INT */ to:172.16.21.1:443
```

Now, I need to route through qmimux0 interface the responses to request that have arrived by this same interface.
For example, I get a request to the qmimux0 public IP (80.80.80.80) at 19443 port; it pass though iptables and arrives to 172.16.21.1 port 443. The response is route through eth1 because it is the default route.

I have tried to use iptables to mark the packets but it didn’t work:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i qmimux0 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add default via 80.80.80.80 table 100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o qmimux0 -m mark --mark 1 -j SNAT --to-source 80.80.80.80
```

tcpdump is showing the packets using the eth1 in the outgoing connections:

```
16:04:20.969197 qmimux0 In  IP 100.100.100.100.49263 > 80.80.80.80.17443: Flags [S], seq 3834440872, win 1024, options [mss 1410], length 0
16:04:20.975831 eth1  Out IP 80.80.80.80.17443 > 100.100.100.100.49263: Flags [S.], seq 3685592694, ack 3834440873, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
16:04:21.996055 eth1  Out IP 80.80.80.80.17443 > 100.100.100.100.49263: Flags [S.], seq 3685592694, ack 3834440873, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
```

I missing something for sure but my knowledge about networks is limited.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

Marks set via `-j MARK` are specific to the packet, so if you mark an incoming packet, this has no effect on outgoing responses by default. You need to set a *connection* mark – in other words, store the packet mark in the conntrack state (the same which handles NAT and "new/established", so it applies equally to UDP as it does to TCP).

After setting the packet mark on the incoming packet, add an additional rule that does `-j CONNMARK` to save it:

```
-t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Then, for outgoing packets, you need to retrieve the mark from conntrack:

```
-t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

---

On the other hand, you probably do not need the manual SNAT rule as this *is* handled by conntrack automatically – if the original packet was NATed, then any packet that matches the "reply-to" of a NATed state will get reverse NAT applied to it (and in fact won't go through the `-t nat` rules at all).

Comment: Thanks @u1686_grawity!
The two rules you put in your comment have to be without any more parameter or have to match the same parameters than previous MARK?
And they have to be the last in the POSTROUTING and PREROUTING chains?

Comment: It really doesn't matter, as long as they're either after the rules that set the mark (in this case after -j MARK), or before the rules that use the mark (in this case there aren't any).